# How do i resolve the error message Type Classname already defines a member called InitializaeComponent with the same parameter types from a VS Project

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

When I run a visual studio 2019 Solution for a Xamarin. Form app I get the error below

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0111  Type 'CreateAccountPage' already defines a member called 'InitializeComponent' with the same parameter types        C:\Users%username%\source\repos\folder\folderr\obj\Debug\netstandard2.0\Views\CreateAccountPage.xaml.g.cs  1

How can I resolve this issue,

Comment: you need to post the relevant code

Answer (score 0):

Locate  the obj folder in C:\Users%username%\source\repos\folder\folderr\obj and delete it, then in visual studio solution explorer right click the solution and select rebuild solution.

This resolved the error message.